# jQuery - filter a div based on anchor tag (click)

Tags: ajax, jquery

Say I have 10 div elements with class **.hide**, which is having different different **Category names** (ex. Food, Travelling, Sports....) in that div content.

```
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide">Foods are Fruits, Chicken, Rice, Pizza...</div>
    <div class="hide">My Travelling places are Bangalore, Goa, Kolkata..</div>
    <div class="hide">Sports :Cricket, Basket ball, Tennis, ..</div>
          .
          .
</div>
```

And say i have 3 anchor tags,

```
<a href="#">Food</a>
<a href="#">Travelling</a>
<a href="#">Sports</a>
         .
         .
```

so, i want to filter these div.hide elements with respected category.

I have done same filtering with check boxes,

```
<script>
    var $filters = $("input:checkbox[name='fli']"); 

var $categoryContent = $('#Categories .hide');
var $errorMessage = $('#errorMessage');
$filters.click(function() {
    // if any of the checkboxes for Category or team are checked, you want to show div's containing their value, and you want to hide all the rest.
    $categoryContent.hide();
     var $selectedFilters = $filters.filter(':checked');
    if ($selectedFilters.length > 0) {
        $errorMessage.hide();
        $selectedFilters.each(function (i, el) {
            $categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + el.value + ')').show();
        });
    } else {
        $errorMessage.show();
    }

});
</script>
```

but i want this one also,

How can i achieve this, please can any one help me.

Thanks

Comment: `$('#Categories.hide')` is an empty selection with your markup, if you want to select all `.hide` elements it should read `$('#Categories .hide')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ENNLn/)

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    $('#Categories > div').addClass('hide')
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').removeClass('hide');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="Food">Food</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="Travelling">Travelling</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="Sports">Sports</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="Food">Foods are Fruits, Chicken, Rice, Pizza...</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="Travelling">My Travelling places are Bangalore, Goa, Kolkata..</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="Sports">Sports :Cricket, Basket ball, Tennis, ..</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="Food">Foods are Fruits, Chicken, Rice, Pizza...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here (right link) it works if you click on anchor tag: http://jsfiddle.net/Z86D7/ Or i don't understand what you are looking for... Could you describe then what you mean by not working?

Comment: If you want the first one to be visible by default, just remove class hide for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Z86D7/1/

Comment: if two or more 'div.hide' are there which contains Food category, that time it should show all those 'div.hide' which containing **Food**

Comment: Wait, how can i divine it following your opening post??? Could you take 2 minutes of your precious time to provide a jsfiddle which reflect your wish then? BTW, none of your categories divs has a name attribute... Filtering by content is an option, but a really bad one

Comment: ya surely...and Thank you to spending your valuable time

Comment: is there any other way to do this other than content

Comment: Ya, use kind of attribute to differenciate each div, i'll suggest you: `data-categorie-type="Food"` etc..  using prefix data make attribute w3c valid. For simplicty, you could use a class too

Comment: i'm already using data-price, can i use data-categorie-type also??

Comment: Ya, for sure, data is not limited

Comment: here, by default i want to display all categories then how?? @roasted

Comment: Well, Naresh, how do you think it could be done? How categories are hidden? How could them be shown? You have to take some initiative, seriously...

Comment: What i'm supposed to check there??? What is the point of this regarding your question here?

Comment: actually i'm trying to give up vote but it is asking reputation i dont that much

Comment: Try that: $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true).change(filterThis).change();  Be aware, i didn't have look in detail your code because it is uggly...

Comment: by using <a href=""></a> tag only i want to show all by default. is it not possible???